# Using land cover shp to extract another category raster for each type in R

Tags: raster, r, shapefile, land-cover, terra

For example,
I have a land cover shp which has 5 types( **'forest','crop','desert','grass','city'** ).
And I have a classfied temperature tif whose values are 1:4, which means **'very high','high','low','very low'**.

```
library(terra)

r1=rast(ncols=,nrows=10,
       vals=sample(c(1:4),100,
                   replace = T))
#1:4 means 'very high','high','low','very low'
plot(r1)

r2=rast(ncols=,nrows=10,
        vals=sample(c(1:5),100,
                    replace = T))
#1:4 means 'forest','crop','desert','grass','city'
#I dong't know how to make a example shp, so I use rast() instead.
plot(r2)
```

I want to know the percentage of each land cover types.
Just like this:
[image]

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to address it.

```
library(terra)    
classified_tem = rast('someone.tif')
# values are 1:4, which means 'very high','high','low','very low'.

landcovershp = vect('landcover.shp')
# This shp has 5 types, ('forest','crop','desert','grass','city').
terra::extract(classified_tem,
               landcovershp,
               fun='table')
```